# Is it possible to use ModelState against a nested Model in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a nested Model ie:

```
MySuperClass
  ConfigClass
  DataClass
```

I pass "MySuperClass" to the View which contains Form. Elements on this form use LINQ to do the model binding, ie:

```
EditorFor(model=>model.DataClass.Name)
EditorFor(model=>model.DataClass.DateOfBirth)
```

I use MySuperClass.ConfigClass properties in the View.

I have Validation DataAnnotations on the DataClass properties such as "Required".

I return back to my form handler in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MySuperClass mySC, string unused = "") 

    //ModelState not firing.... on empty required columns
    if (ModelState.IsValid))
```

I quess "mySuperClass" is like a ViewModel.

How can I get the Validation to work?

EDIT

Also using using the Validation Helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.DataClass.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataClass.Name)
```

Comment: Can you show us the specific code for the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested objects *will* be validated, as long as they are not null, so you just need to ensure that `Model.DataClass` is an instance of `DataClass` and not null. The easiest way to do that is in the constructor of `MySuperClass`:

```
public MySuperClass()
{
     DataClass = new DataClass();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am actually newing up the instance in the ctor. Also if "DataClass" was null then I would get nulls in my EditorFor fields which I am not. I get the values coming in, and I can edit and save them, and they save fine, except everything is treated as valid. It is as if the Validator is only checking "MySuperClass" rather than "MySuperClass.DataClass". I am testing with based "Required" validators. Thanks again.

Comment: Is `ModelState.IsValid` actually returning true, or are you just allowed to submit the form without the required fields?

Comment: Now found to be returning False, so is working. Not quite sure what I did, may the result of fixing another bug. But good to know that I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same trouble as yours in one of my project like this, you need to create filter and use it in both sending from action to view and also posting from view to action(Post action):

```
public abstract class ModelStateBase : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected static readonly string Key = typeof(ModelStateBase).FullName;
}

public class OnGetMetaData : ModelStateBase
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if ((filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) || (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult))
            {
                filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

public class OnPostMetaData : ModelStateBase
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

        if (modelState != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(Key);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and in the get and post action you can act like this:

```
  [OnPostMetaData]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost, OnGetMetaData]
    public ActionResult Index(MySuperClass mySuperClass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
        }

        return View();
    }
```

and finally the view is the same as regular form as you have used.

Comment: Thank you for this, but the existing nested classes do actually validate.

Answer (score 1):

The nested models should work in MVC 3. Please try with this sample.

### Controller & Class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IndexNew()
    {
        Sample obj = new Sample() {MyTest=new Test() };
        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexNew(Sample test)
    {            
        return View(test);
    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public Test MyTest { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### View Part

```
    @model MvcApplication2.Controllers.Sample

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "IndexNew";
    }

    <h2>IndexNew</h2>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sample</legend>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.MyTest.Name);

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive effort. I sort of got there with Chris's help and my bug fixes, and he was sooner.